# Ubuntu 16.04 IntelliJ launcher dissapears after reboot

Tags: ubuntu, intellij-idea

I have this problem when i reboot my launcher to IDEA just disappears. What I've done was:

1. Launched IDEA with "./idea.sh"
2. Then made desktop entry "tools" > "create desktop entry"
3. Closed IDEA and Launched from Dash
4. Then I pinned to the Launcher

But there's the problem that after reboot it just disappears. Not sure if problem is related with this but I have IDEA installed in different partition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved this problem by making my partition to automatically mount.